# Ignore health check for Supervisord entry

Tags: linux, supervisord

I want to run a one-time script once the system is up, And I can see in the logs that I have an exception that coming from the health check, How can I make this check redundant? I don't want further checks after the script is done.

`supervisord.conf:`

```
[program:matiprocedure]
priority=1000
command=/bin/bash /tmp/startup.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=false
numprocs=1
health_check_interval = 0
```

`/tmp/startup.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e /tmp/log.txt ]; then #make it run once.
  echo "Starting MATI procedure..."
  sleep 10
  echo "After 10 seconds..."
  whoami > /tmp/log.txt

  # Read the output file and save the contents to a variable
  output=$(cat /tmp/log.txt)
  exit 0
fi
```

Did I set the attributes correctly for the one-time running script?